# CQ accessing from VB script

Tags: vbscript, aem

Is there any error in the following code?

```
Call Operator.BuildFilter(strFilterFieldName2, AD_COMP_OP_BETWEEN, filterValues2)
```

Comment: I am getting object not defined error.

Comment: My code Contains below 2 lines                                                            Call Operator.BuildFilter(strFilterFieldName1, AD_COMP_OP_EQ, filterValues1)    Call Operator.BuildFilter(strFilterFieldName2, AD_COMP_OP_BETWEEN,   filterValues2) --> is there any problem in bridging these 2 lines?

Comment: and here Set Operator = querydef.BuildFilterOperator(AD_BOOL_OP_AND)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve it rather than posting additional info in comments. http://stackexchange.com/sites is not a chat.